# "Atomic" Multiple Substitution in Vim

Tags: vim

I know how to do multiple substitutions at once in vim but this only behaves correctly if none of the substitutes match a subsequent item to be replaced. This can be worked around by using temporary substitutes to avoid collision that are later replaced with the proper string, but this is messy.

What is the best way to do something like this in vim?

```
a b c d e
```

becomes

```
b c d e a
```

In this case each item has a unique substitution but I would like as general and frictionless a solution as possible. Don't focus on what regexes are needed, but rather how to accomplish the multiple substitutions in one operation so there is no intermediate state where an incorrect substitution will occur.

Comment: You can use VIM dictionary for that, as described by **rampion** in this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/765894/can-i-substitute-multiple-items-in-a-single-regular-expression-in-vim-or-perl#answer-766093 .